# FFMpeg : GIF to MP4 conversion throws code error.

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a GIF to a MP4. I am getting an error while doing that with specific parameters. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be nice. I would like a mp4 video with high quality, size is not a problem.

Command and log :

```
ffmpeg -i So_gehts.gif -c:v libvpx -crf 4 -b:v 500K output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.1 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 20151010
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.15.10.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openal --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-libssh --enable-libsoxr --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-libx265
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, gif, from 'So_gehts.gif':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 374x461, 29.25 fps, 100 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libvpx @ 0x16a5940] v1.4.0
[mp4 @ 0x168ec60] Could not find tag for codec vp8 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuva420p, 374x461, q=-1--1, 500 kb/s, 100 fps, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libvpx
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your error message...

```
codec not currently supported in container
```

I don't think you can use VP8 with an MP4.  Try a different codec or container format?  I've provided some examples with links to documentation below.

[MP4 w/ x264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264):

```
ffmpeg -i So_gehts.gif -c:v libx264 -crf 4 -b:v 500K output.mp4
```

[MP4 w/ x264 (lossless)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264):

```
ffmpeg -i So_gehts.gif -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mp4
```

[WebM w/ VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8):

```
ffmpeg -i So_gehts.gif -c:v libvpx -crf 4 -b:v 1M output.webm
```

[WebM w/ VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9):

```
ffmpeg -i So_gehts.gif -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 0 -b:v 0 output.webm
```

Comment: The libx264 worked. It has increased the size of the video, does it have any change in quality as well?

Comment: VP8/VP9 should be of comparable quality to x264.  If you're curious, you can always create a WebM with VP8 and a WebM with VP9 and compare all three.

Comment: The mp4 didn't work in browser, had to use the webm. Thanks.. :-)